# Unity and Android Studio integration hardware not supported

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have attempted to integrate simple Unity shape figure to display using Android Studio IDE however it shows like this:

> Your hardware does not support this application sorry

My phone is Android 6.0 Marshmallow and the version of Unity is 5.4.1f1

The logcat in Android Studio does not show any error except when I dismiss the message about hardware not supported, then crashed.

```
package com.cs4.android_lcitresearch.schoolsafetyemergencyapplication.maps_class;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cs4.android_lcitresearch.schoolsafetyemergencyapplication.R;
import com.cs4.android_lcitresearch.schoolsafetyemergencyapplication.SplashInterface;
import com.cs4.android_lcitresearch.schoolsafetyemergencyapplication.comic_class.comiclass;
import com.cs4.android_lcitresearch.schoolsafetyemergencyapplication.phone_class.phoneclass;
import com.cs4.android_lcitresearch.schoolsafetyemergencyapplication.scenario_class.scenarioclass;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class lcoldclass extends AppCompatActivity {

protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;
public static Context mContext;
private Handler handler=new Handler();

public FrameLayout fl_forUnity;
public ImageButton  scenario1, comic1, phoneclass1, maps1,  homeb;
public Toolbar toolbar;
public TextView txttitle;
public void init_home() {
    homeb= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.homebutton);
    homeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent first = new Intent(lcoldclass.this,SplashInterface.class);
            startActivity(first);
        }
    });
}


public void init_scenario() {
    scenario1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.scenario);
    scenario1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent first = new Intent(lcoldclass.this,scenarioclass.class);
            startActivity(first);
        }
    });
}

public void init_comic() {
    comic1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.comicbutton);
    comic1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent first = new Intent(lcoldclass.this,comiclass.class);
            startActivity(first);
        }
    });
}

public void init_phone() {
    phoneclass1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.callbutton);
    phoneclass1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent first = new Intent(lcoldclass.this,phoneclass.class);
            startActivity(first);
        }
    });
}

public void init_maps() {
    maps1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mapsl);
    maps1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent first = new Intent(lcoldclass.this,SecondInterfaceF.class);
            startActivity(first);
        }
    });
}



private void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.include2);

    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mContext = this;
    getWindow().takeSurface(null);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_888);


    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);


    if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
        getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

    View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();


    setContentView(R.layout.lcmapsold1);

    this.fl_forUnity = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameunity);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(750, 630);

    fl_forUnity.addView(playerView, 0, lp);


    initToolbar();
    init_home();
    init_scenario();
    init_comic();
    init_phone();
    init_maps();

    txtformation_init();

    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
}


///////////////////////////// Unity Codes Override///////////////////////////////////////////
// Quit Unity
@Override protected void onDestroy ()
{
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
    super.onDestroy();
}

// Pause Unity
@Override protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

// Resume Unity
@Override protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}

// This ensures the layout will be correct.
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// Notify Unity of the focus change.
@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}

// For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
// Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

// Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
@Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
/*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }


///////////////////////////// Unity Codes Override///////////////////////////////////////////


}
```

How to solve it? I cannot understand how users manage to work the program without issues on integration.

Comment: when building in unity in Player Settings toggle full logging on every level. in build settings check 'development build'. try again

Comment: @NikaKasradze: I will try but what if it's not working? Cause I try that way back before and the issue persist.

Comment: @NikaKasradze: Not working :(

Comment: I dont know. It is a little unclear what you are trying to do. Just to make sure we are on the same page: so in unity you have opened build settings, marked the Google Android Project tick, built, opened in Android Studio, added this class and it does not build right?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I've added the class then entered the source code for Unity however when the program run; a pop-up shown stated "Your hardware is not supported".

Comment: Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: :(, Have you experience some sort of that error? Where you build the program using Android Studio embedded with Unity?

Comment: the only hardware unity interacts with directly is GPU. So maybe in Unity's build settings you have to make sure you have "Automatic Graphics API" checked. Also if rendering path is not set to "Forward" set it so.

Comment: So it is nothing related about incompatibility of smartphones where the hardware is not supported?

Comment: I cant tell unless youve tested my suggestion

Comment: @NikaKasradze: I'm  afraid cause I checked carefully through Unity Build settings then tried to import in Android Studio, still the error goes same.